# False result in Elastic Search Query below

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm new to elastic search and I'm using it for the first time to index my data and perform search on it.

I wrote this code to find count of terms in index:

```
{
  {
    "size": 0
  },
  "aggs": {
    "BookID": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "bookID",
        "size": 100000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_Chapter": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "chapterData"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "termsInChapter": {
              "filters": {
                "filters": {
                  "king": {
                    "query_string": {
                      "query": "king",
                      "default_field": "chapter.data"
                    }
                  },
                  "queen": {
                    "query_string": {
                      "query": "queen",
                      "default_field": "chapter.data"
                    }
                  },
                  "apple": {
                    "query_string": {
                      "query": "apple",
                      "default_field": "chapter.data"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "termsInChapter_count": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "termsInChapter"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But somehow result is returning 0. I don't know what I did wrong in this query.

Here is the part of the output of this query:

```
"aggregations": {
    "BookID": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 1,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "total_Chapter": {
            "doc_count": 23,
            "termsInChapter": {
              "buckets": {
                "apple": {
                  "doc_count": 2
                },
                "king": {
                  "doc_count": 1
                },
                "queen": {
                  "doc_count": 1
                }
              }
            },
            "termsInChapter_count": {
              "value": 0              <=========This should return 3
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 2,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "total_Chapter": {
            "doc_count": 23,
            "termsInChapter": {
              "buckets": {
                "apple": {
                  "doc_count": 0
                },
                "king": {
                  "doc_count": 3
                },
                "queen": {
                  "doc_count": 2
                }
              }
            },
            "termsInChapter_count": {
              "value": 0
            }
          }
        },
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks to [Andrei Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3498062/andrei-stefan) for the help.

I'm answering this question directly so that anyone can get direct answer without going through comments and all.

Going through your [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43936580/6270267) answer, I found that `bucket_script` should be placed on a higher level. So I slightly changed your query from last answer and it worked.

Here is the final working query:

```
"aggs": {
  "total_Chapter": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "chapterData"
    },
    "aggs": {
      "termsInChapter": {
        "filters": {
          "filters": {
            "king": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "king",
                "default_field": "chapter.data"
              }
            },
            "queen": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "queen",
                "default_field": "chapter.data"
              }
            },
            "apple": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "apple",
                "default_field": "chapter.data"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "filter_zero_matches_buckets": {
            "bucket_selector": {
              "buckets_path": {
                "hits": "_count"
              },
              "script": "params.hits > 0"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "termsInChapter_count": {
    "bucket_script": {
      "buckets_path": {
        "bucket_count": "total_Chapter>termsInChapter._bucket_count"
      },
      "script": "params.bucket_count"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks again [Andrei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3498062/andrei-stefan). :)

Comment: Yeah, to simplify my tests I didn't test with `nested` data structure. Glad that you made it work in the end :-).

Answer (score 1):

Your `termsInChapter_count` aggregation needs to refer to a field, not an aggregation name, that's why your solution doesn't work.

For that to work you need a `sum_bucket` type of aggregation:

```
"termsInChapter_count": {
  "sum_bucket": {
    "buckets_path": "termsInChapter._count"
  }
}
```

**LATER EDIT**

```
  "aggs": {
    "termsInChapter": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "king": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "king",
              "default_field": "chapter.data"
            }
          },
          "queen": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "queen",
              "default_field": "chapter.data"
            }
          },
          "apple": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "apple",
              "default_field": "chapter.data"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filter_zero_matches_buckets": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "hits": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.hits > 0"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "termsInChapter_count": {
      "bucket_script": {
        "buckets_path": {
          "bucket_count": "termsInChapter._bucket_count"
        },
        "script": "params.bucket_count"
      }
    }
  }
```

What you are looking for in the results is `termsInChapter_count` value.

Comment: This returns the sum of count from all buckets. What I want is number of terms matched not the sum of count of terms matched.

Comment: What should I do for it?

Comment: I'm not following. You want the number of buckets?

Comment: I want number of terms matched... Let say I have searched for four terms but three of them matched I want '3' in the result and Now if I search for five terms and two of them matches I want '2' in the result. Thanks

Comment: I see now. I updated the answer with something that should do it, but it's more complicated.

Comment: Thanks @andrei-stefan. I have updated my code, but it is throwing an exception in sense. Here is the Exception `"error": {
    "root_cause": [],
    "type": "reduce_search_phase_exception",
    "reason": "[reduce] ",
    "phase": "fetch",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [],
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "class_cast_exception",
      "reason": "org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.nested.InternalNested cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.InternalMultiBucketAggregation"
    }
  },
  "status": 503`